# Windows Update Executable Path

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-update, windows-firewall, whitelist

I am setting up application whitelisting using Windows Firewall and part of that process is allowing Windows Update, but I cannot seem to find where the executable is located.  This is for both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

Comment: Windows Update is a service not an application.

Comment: See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693717.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Windows Update is an system service, not an application. When checking the service properties, you can see:

[image]

Windows Update services runs with the system process: svchost.exe and it is using ports: 80, 443.

By default, Windows Firewall will not block the Windows Update. If you want to control it, please allow the svchost.exe and ports: 80, 443.